Weak derivative operator is not sequentially continuous in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$
Suppose we have a sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that $u_n\to u$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and all the functions $u_n$ and $u$ have first order weak derivatives $\partial_i u_n$ and $\partial_i u$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, respectively. Then for all $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, we have
$$[*]\quad\int_\Omega \partial_i u_n\;\varphi\to\int_\Omega \partial_i u\;\varphi,$$
which of course implies that $\partial_i u_n$ converges to $\partial_i u$ in the sense of distributions.
Does [*] imply convergence in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ i.e. $\partial_i u_n\to \partial_i u$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$?
I'm sure that the answer is NO because the weak derivative operator is not sequentially continuous in the topology of $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, but I cannot find an example which illustrates this setting. Can you give me some lights for this situation?

Take a sequence of smooth functions converging to the signum function, then the derivatives will converge to a Dirac delta, which is not locally integrable

@LL 3.14 Thanks for the reply. The example you give does not satisfy the requirements since the signum function does not have weak derivative in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$. It has distributional derivative which is precisely the Dirac mass distribution.
